# Dismiss keyboard when tapping on an UITextField with custom inputView

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I have three UITextFields

UITextField1 <- shows keyboard

UITextField2 <- shows keyboard

UITextField3 <- shows custom inputView (pickerView)

When finishing editing textField2, I click "next" on the keyboard, it hides the keyboard but the picker its not shown.

If I finish editing textField2 and without closing the keyboard and tap on textField3, the keyboard is not hidden and the picker shows above the keyboard, then the keyboard cannot be closed unless I return to textField2 and tap outside any textField.

snippet:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.textField3){
        // Close the keyboard.

        [self.textField3 resignFirstResponder];

        [self.view endEditing:YES];

        ActionSheetDatePicker *picker;

        NSString *fechaIni = [self.dates objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fechaFin = [self.dates objectAtIndex:[self.dates count]-1];

        NSDate *fechaMarcada;

        if(self.fecha == nil){
            fechaMarcada = [self fromDateString:fechaIni format:@"yyyyMMdd"];
        }else{
            fechaMarcada = self.fecha;
        }

        picker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"Seleccione" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:fechaMarcada target:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) origin:textField cancelAction:nil];

        [picker setMinimumDate:[self fromDateString:fechaIni format:@"yyyyMMdd"]];
        [picker setMaximumDate:[self fromDateString:fechaFin format:@"yyyyMMdd"]];

        [picker setDoneButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]];
        [picker setCancelButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancelar" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]];
        [picker showActionSheetPicker];

        self.textField3.inputView = picker.pickerView;
        self.textField3.text = [Utils formatDate:[self formatDate:fechaMarcada]];

        [Utils animateScreenUpByHalfKeyboardHeight:self.view];

    }else if(textField == self.textField1){
        if([self.currency.code isEqualToString:@"USD"]){
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
        }else{
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I close the keyboard in all situations before showing the pickerView in textField3?

Edit based on rmp suggestion

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [Utils navigationBarTitleAndSubtitle:self title:@"Title" subtitle:@"Subtitle"];

    NSString *fechaIni = [self.dates objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fechaFin = [self.dates objectAtIndex:[self.dates count]-1];

    NSDate *fechaMarcada;

    if(self.fecha == nil){
       fechaMarcada = [self fromDateString:fechaIni format:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    }else{
       fechaMarcada = self.fecha;
    }

   self.picker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"Seleccione" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:fechaMarcada target:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) origin:self.textField3 cancelAction:nil];

   [self.picker setMinimumDate:[self fromDateString:fechaIni format:@"yyyyMMdd"]];
   [self.picker setMaximumDate:[self fromDateString:fechaFin format:@"yyyyMMdd"]];

   [self.picker setDoneButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]];
   [self.picker setCancelButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancelar" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]];
   //[self.picker showActionSheetPicker];

   self.textField3.inputView = self.picker.pickerView;
   self.textField3.text = [Utils formatDate:[self formatDate:fechaMarcada]];
}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.textField3){
        // Close the keyboard.
        // [self.view endEditing:YES];

        [Utils animateScreenUpByHalfKeyboardHeight:self.view];

    }else if(textField == self.textField1){
        if([self.currency.code isEqualToString:@"USD"]){
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
        }else{
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add a gesture recognizer like this. Make sure to add this UIGestureRecognizerDelegate at top of your class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    self. UITextField1!.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
    tap1.delegate = self
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to config picker every time before show.
Move this code to viewDid load or to viewWillAppear

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    picker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"Seleccione" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:fechaMarcada target:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) origin:textField cancelAction:nil];

        [picker setMinimumDate:[self fromDateString:fechaIni format:@"yyyyMMdd"]];
        [picker setMaximumDate:[self fromDateString:fechaFin format:@"yyyyMMdd"]];

        [picker setDoneButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]];
        [picker setCancelButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancelar" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]];
        [picker showActionSheetPicker];

        self.textField3.inputView = picker.pickerView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it may have to do with this code snippet here

```css
self.textField3.inputView = picker.pickerView;
        self.textField3.text = [Utils formatDate:[self formatDate:fechaMarcada]];

        [Utils animateScreenUpByHalfKeyboardHeight:self.view];
```

in which case I think you should delete

```
[Utils animateScreenUpByHalfKeyboardHeight:self.view];
```

the gesture recognition answer is probably right though

Comment: No, that line has nothing to do. The screen animation is correct, the problem is that the picker is above the keyboard because the keyboard is not dismissed.

Comment: yea I wasnt entirely clear as to what you meant by picker, my bad. Have you tried the other two answers yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `ActionSheetDatePicker` init code to either `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` so it is initialized before the user acts on the text field. You need this so `textField3.inputView` has already been assigned before the user enters the field. Now you can remove the line of code `[self.textField3 resignFirstResponder];` as your text field will not present the keyboard as it's `inputView` has already been assigned to the `ActionSheetDatePicker`

Comment: didn't work. Keeps showing keyboard instead of picker

Comment: can you edit your questions to show the revised code?

Comment: it could be an issue with `ActionSheetDatePicker`  As a test, replace it with a standard `UIDatePicker` and see it at works.  If so, you will know the issue is with the `ActionSheetDatePicker`